# Android Studio Ad in Widget

Tags: java, android, widget, admob, ads

is it possible to show an ad in a widget in android studio? I've already read some posts about this topic and found out that mobile ads need a "WebView". Widgets do support certain views, but not the required "WebView".
I got this info out of following discussion (2016): https://groups.google.com/g/google-admob-ads-sdk/c/crEu0FsSs0Q .

Does anyone of you know if they added something since then or if it's still not possible. I also would be interested in any workarounds if you got some.

I've already tested to implement a basic widget with an an ad, provided from AdMob for terms of testing, but the widget only shows the text "Can't load widget".

**Java:**

```
public class AdWidget extends AppWidgetProvider {

    @Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
        // There may be multiple widgets active, so update all of them
        for (int appWidgetId : appWidgetIds) {
            updateAppWidget(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetId);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onEnabled(Context context) {
        // Enter relevant functionality for when the first widget is created
    }

    @Override
    public void onDisabled(Context context) {
        // Enter relevant functionality for when the last widget is disabled
    }

    static void updateAppWidget(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
            int appWidgetId) {

        CharSequence widgetText = context.getString(R.string.appwidget_text);
        // Construct the RemoteViews object
        RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.ad_widget);

        // Instruct the widget manager to update the widget
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
    }
}
```

**XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/AdWidget_Body"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".AdWidget">

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/AdWidget_Ad"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111">

    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Thanks,

Niklas

Comment: "I've already read some posts about this topic and found out that mobile ads need a "WebView"" -- your code uses `com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView`. App widgets can use neither that nor `WebView`, and there is no requirement for the launcher app to have the SDK for any particular ad network.